# Java regex matcher always returns false

Tags: java, regex

I have a string expression from which I need to get some values. The string is as follows

```
#min({(((fields['example6'].value + fields['example5'].value) * ((fields['example1'].value*5)+fields['example2'].value+fields['example3'].value-fields['example4'].value)) * 0.15),15,9.087})
```

From this stribg, I need to obtain a string array list which contains the values such as "example1", "example2" and so on.

I have a Java method which looks like this:

```
String regex = "/fields\\[['\"]([\\w\\s]+)['\"]\\]/g";
ArrayList<String> arL = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(expression);

while(m.find()){
    arL.add(m.group());
}
```

But `m.find()` always returns `false`. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: You don't use `/.../g` syntax in Java regex. They are regex delimiter in other languages, which is not necessary in Java. Remove them, and your regex will work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the '/'s. If what you want to extract is only the field name, you should use m.group(1):

```
String regex = "fields\\[['\"]([\\w\\s]+)['\"]\\]";
ArrayList<String> arL = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(expression);

while(m.find()){
    arL.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you seem to have is that you are using delimiters (as in PHP or Perl or JavaScript) that cannot be used in a Java regex. Also, you have your matches in the first capturing group, but you are using `group()` that returns the whole match (including `fields['`).

Here is a working code:

```
String str = "#min({(((fields['example6'].value + fields['example5'].value) * ((fields['example1'].value*5)+fields['example2'].value+fields['example3'].value-fields['example4'].value)) * 0.15),15,9.087})";
ArrayList<String> arL = new ArrayList<String>();
String rx = "(?<=fields\\[['\"])[\\w\\s]*(?=['\"]\\])";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    arL.add(m.group());
}
```

Here is a [working IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ifNWZ9)

Note that I have added look-arounds to extract just the texts between `'`s with `group()`.